# Evaluation the integral in complex analysis

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^23\theta\, d\theta}{5-4\cos2\theta}.$$
In complex analysis, I want to solve the below problem. I know already the answer. But it is not easy to verify the answer. The function in the integral has a pole of order $5$ at $z=0$. it is strange.... The calculation is too hard. Please, help me...

Comment: Which function has a pole of order 5 at z=0? Said differently, you might want to show what you did to solve the question, this is the interesting part...

Comment: If you put z=e^{i\theta} (0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi), then you can know the problem. The calculation will be complicated. But I want to verify the result using complex analysis techniques.

Comment: My point is that the text of your question should explain this, to be complete (not that I would want to "know the problem", whatever that means). "The calculation will be complicated" Not really, actually.

Comment: Put $$z=e^{i\theta} (0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi)$$. Then the above problem is $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{12}+2z^{6}+1}{-4z^{5}(2z^{4}-5z^{2}+2)}\frac{dz}{i}$$. So, the function in the integral has a pole of order 5 at z=0. Then the calculation of the residue is complicated. I think there exists the more simple method to get the residue.

Comment: **In the question**, please...

Comment: Just as a comment, it is amazing to see how "simple" and "beautiful" is the corresponding antiderivative ! But this is  absolutely of no help for your problem.

Answer (score -2):

**Hint:** Using the change of variable $z=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta}$, this is, up to multiplicative constants I will let you discover, the complex integral on the unit circle of the function $f$ defined by
$$
f(z)=\frac{(z^3+z^{-3})^2}{5-2z^2-2z^{-2}}\frac1z\propto\frac1{z^5}g(z),
$$
where
$$
g(z)=\frac{(1+z^6)^2}{1-\frac52z^2+z^4},
$$
and the question is to determine the coefficient of $z^4$ in the expansion of $g(z)$.

To do so, first note that the numerator is $1+O(z^6)$ hence it does not contribute. Using $w=\frac52z^2-z^4$, the expansion $\frac1{1-w}=1+w+w^2+O(w^3)$ and the fact that $O(w^3)=O(z^6)$, one sees that
$$
g(z)=\frac1{1-w}+O(z^6)=1+\left(\frac52z^2-z^4\right)+\left(\frac52z^2\right)^2+O(z^6),
$$
hence the $z^4$ term in $g(z)$ is $-z^4+\left(\frac52z^2\right)^2$, from which the answer follows.